# Lucene.NET Duplicating result in C#

Tags: c#, lucene

My result is duplicating when i used Lucene.NET

Here is my code

```
    public DataTable search(string txtSearch)
    {
        var table = GetData().Clone();
        var Index = createIndex();
        var reader = IndexReader.Open(Index, true);
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

        var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30,
            "legal head|subjectmatter|issues1|principle".Split('|'), analyzer);
        var Searchquery = queryParser.Parse(txtSearch);

        TopScoreDocCollector collecctor = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(500, true);
        searcher.Search(Searchquery, collecctor);

        ScoreDoc[] matches = collecctor.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            var id = item.Doc;
            var doc = searcher.Doc(id);

            var row = table.NewRow();
            row["legal head"] = doc.GetField("legal head").StringValue;
            row["subjectmatter"] = doc.GetField("subjectmatter").StringValue;
            row["issues1"] = doc.GetField("issues1").StringValue;
            row["principle"] = doc.GetField("principle").StringValue;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is showing the data more than once

Comment: the data will shows 500., and i think is because of TopScoreDocCollector.Create(500, true);